# Moving rows from one database to another using mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

My question is pretty straight-forward, and I assume that people need to do this pretty often; yet, after hours of searching online, nothing especially enlightening has come up. I am aware of a thread on here about doing the same thing using PDO, but I want to stick to mysqli to be consistent across my whole site.

So, I need to move one or several rows from one database to another (and NOT from one table to another within a single database).

The code I have so far is sure to get some laughs, as this task proved to be considerably beyond my ability. Anyway, here goes:

To begin with, I have two `mysqli_connect`... not sure if that is encouraged, although it has not caused me problems so far.

```
$connect_MAIN = mysqli_connect($servername_MAIN, $username_MAIN, $password_MAIN, $dbname_MAIN); 
$connect_TEMP = mysqli_connect($servername_TEMP, $username_TEMP, $password_TEMP, $dbname_TEMP);
```

Here is the meat in the sandwich in terms of code:

```
///Prepare this in advance because the 'IN' values are taken from a $_GET
$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM Concert WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)";

///Connect to source DB
$result = $connect_TEMP->query($sql_select);

if ($result->num_rows != 0) {

    ///Connect to destination DB
        $stmt = $connect_MAIN->prepare('INSERT INTO Concert (venue_id, date, ensemble_id, info, title, repertoire, time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
        $venue_id = $date = $ensemble_id = $info = $title = $repertoire = $time = null;
        $stmt->bind_param("isissss", $venue_id, $date, $ensemble_id, $info, $title, $repertoire, $time);

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $venue_id = $row["venue_id"];
            $date = $row["date"];
            $ensemble_id = $row["ensemble_id"];
            $info = $row["info"];
            $title = $row["title"];
            $repertoire = $row["repertoire"];
            $time = $row["time"];


            if ($stmt->execute() === TRUE) {
                if ($show_once == 1) {
                    echo "Info successfully submitted.";
                    $show_once = 0;
                }
            } else { 
                echo "Hmm, something went wrong..." . $connect_MAIN->error;
            }
        }
    }
$stmt->close();
mysqli_close($connect_TEMP); 
}
```

So, I know that this is a bit of a jumble... as I said, I am not sure if it is possible to connect to DB2 in the middle of a `while` loop returning values from DB1. Feel free to mock, but only if you have something useful to suggest!

Comment: You're not quoting your variables on your insert. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). This will fix any and all quoting issues.

Comment: It's also not clear why you have a single escaped quote in later on in the query.

Comment: @Barmar Are you referring to this: ')'); ??

Comment: @PaulClift No, this: `$row["info"] . '\', '`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Isn't that necessary to properly format the string for Mysql?

Comment: Also, so in your opinion(s), it is not problematic to access a second database in this way? This was the cause of most of the doubt in my mind...

Comment: No, it's not problematic to connect to multiple databases. You can connect to thousands in a single script if you wish. The problem lies in building your `INSERT` as it is not being built properly. However, issuing new connections to the same database could cause you a myriad of issues.

Comment: No, it shouldn't be an issue. I believe I did something like this before to sync an external system.

Comment: I appreciate all your help... but unfortunately it is still not working (returns nothing)... I have updated the code in the question. Perhaps you could take a quick look?

Comment: You completely changed the question.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Not really... I just switched to using a prepared statement. Everything else is as it was...

Comment: Oh, and there are some more vars in there, because that is what I am really using. I trimmed down some of that in my original post, as it was redundant for the purposes of asking for help.

Comment: `if ($show_once == 1) {` is never triggered because `$show_once` is not pre-defined. In all honestly, forget about `$show_once` and just check your DB for data; stop unnecessarily complicating this.

Comment: That is a minor complication that I can live with, and it is defined higher up in the code.

Comment: Well then having two `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {` should qualify as a major complication.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus You're dead right about that! That was a typo when I was editing the question. Have changed it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a parametrized query instead of concatenating strings.

```
///Prepare this in advance because the 'IN' values are taken from a $_GET
$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM Concert WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)";

///Connect to source DB
$result = $connect_TEMP->query($sql_select);
if ($result->num_rows != 0) {
    ///Connect to destination DB
    $stmt = $connect_MAIN->prepare('INSERT INTO Concert (venue, date, info, time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');
    $venue = $date = $info = $time = null;
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $venue, $date, $info, $time);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $venue = $row["venue"];
        $date = $row["date"];
        $info = $row["info"];
        $time = $row["time"];
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            ///This is just to stop message from appearing multiple times.
            if ($show_once == 1) {
                echo "Info successfully submitted.";
                $show_once = 0;
            }
        } else { 
            echo "Hmm, something went wrong..." . $stmt->error;
        }
    }
    $stmt->close();
    mysqli_close($connect_TEMP); 
}
```

Comment: Quick question about your code -- is it a problem when binding that some of the vars would not be strings, but rather, ints, in the SQL database? Is it important to specify that? Or does Sql take the string as an int without complaining?

Comment: You can change the `s` to `i` for those columns in the `bind_param()` call. But MySQL will also automatically convert, so it's usually not critical.

Comment: I appreciate your help but I am still stuck on this.... I have made those changes, but the process is mysteriously stopping at `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())`. I'd really appreciate any suggestions you may have.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why it would stop there.

Comment: You've completely rewritten the code in the question. Please don't do that. If you want to show your attempt to use my answer, add it as an addition, but keep the original.

Comment: Now no one can see what I was answering, and it looks like I'm telling you to do what you were already doing.

Comment: In my experience, editing original questions is standard practice on here. My apologies if I was mistaken.

Comment: You can edit the question to make minor fixes, but if the edit completely obscures the original problem it's not correct. Add the new code to the end instead of replacing.

Comment: Like if you made a copying error that caused a misunderstanding of the question, you can edit that.

Comment: But the problem remains! The only changes I made were to switch the SQL query to a prepared statement, which was never the issue here.

Comment: There shouldn't be any such conflict. What error are you getting now?

Comment: It was an issue with the login, I solved it. Thanks very much for your help though!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you may establish a second DB connection at any point in your script. There's nothing preventing it nor there's a reason to discourage it. It's far more common than you'd think (for different reasons). However, considering the overhead that actually connecting to the database carries, I would advice you to not establish a connection on each iteration (this is the best practice, performance-wise)

What I would do:

> 1. First, connect to the source database, get the data you need

Not much to say here, you already did and it looks OK. Check, as you did, that there's at least one result before moving on. If the resultset is empty, don't go any further (exit)

> 2. If there was at least one row in the resultset, establish a connection to the destination database

Do this **before** starting to loop to avoid the performance penalty of establishing multiple connections. If you're looking at hundreds/thousands or more rows, you'll really notice the difference. Once the connection is established, move on

> 3. Loop through the source data and prepare the insert statements

You have a choice here. Either a) loop through the whole resultset and prepare one single insert with multiple rows which you'll insert all at once at the end of the loop or b) create a single insert (single row) on each iteration, run the insert and then move on to the next iteration.

There's reasons for and against both strategies. Choose the one that suits you better.

In algorythmical terms, your code is pretty much ready (just connect to the destination DB once before you start looping). You may benefit from using a parameterized query with bindings instead of writing the full insert string, but other than that you're pretty much there.

Comment: Excellent advice like this should show up in google searches!

Answer (score 1):

If you are running your own MySql server, you may do this in a simpler way using the [Federated](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-description.html) engine.

The federated table behaves like a normal table, but it stores the data in a remote database. With this engine you can do someting like this:

```
INSERT INTO remoteTable (values) SELECT * FROM localTable
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I did not know about that!